# Password field is not showing in localAuthenticationContext

Tags: ios, swift

```
localAuthenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reasonString) { success, error in
    // a popup is shown but there is no password option. Only cancel button
});
```

I want to show the popup with cancel and also a password option. Assume device password is enabled.

Comment: At first, TouchId / Face Id is tried. You should fail 1 time to be able to test the pasword

Comment: I dont want to fail. I want both options initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your asking is not possible. You should try at least 1 touchId Authentication

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy/deviceownerauthentication?changes=_2